# Bitcoin accepted charities or organizations

Tags: charity

I'm looking for Bitcoin accepted Charities. I want to make a list of the charities.

I found that [Donation-accepting organizations and projects](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Donation-accepting_organizations_and_projects) but I prefer organizations which are saving children, providing educations or solving environmental issues. Typical examples are UNICEF and WWF.

And also, I need to know the charitable bitcoin address. I mean that using payment processer, like bitpay, are not useful in my case.

The followings are what I found it.

- [BitGive](http://bitgivefoundation.org/)
- [Dignitas International](http://dignitasinternational.org/)

Are there any organizations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[GiveBTC](http://givebtc.org/index.php/bitcoin-donation-directory/) by the Bitcoin Foundation Canada / Bitcoin Embassy is the best directory I've seen.  Linked from the top of that page, they also have an excellent handbook for charities considering accepting bitcoin donations.

> I need to know the charitable bitcoin address. I mean that using payment processer, like bitpay, are not useful in my case.

I'm sorry to hear that.  Neither individuals nor organizations should be [reusing addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse) because it reduces their privacy and the privacy of all Bitcoin users they transact with.  Here's a [related answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/35419/21052) I wrote.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's very useful. Regarding payment processer, yes I agree with you but I was looking for in this mine case.

Comment: And what you mentioned was very interesting. I'll check it in detail.